# How to access/obtain Powershell DNS Server module on 2012r2?

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, powershell-v4.0

I'm working on a Server 2012R2 server.
I want to use the comdlets like `get-dnsserverresourcerecord` in the [dns server module for PowerShell](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/dnsserver/dnsserver).

It is not available in the ISE or in the list of modules.

I have powershell version 4.0.  I am operating on server 2012r2.
Where can I find this module?  Is it possible to download or enable this module? I've looked at a lot of docs and posts, and they are all written in such a way that indicates the module should just be installed.

My plan is to use this server to execute DNS commands against another 2012r2 server running a DNS server.  This server itself does not have a DNS server intalled.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Budris

On your management server install the Remote Server Administration Tools > Role Administration tools > DNS Server tools by using Server Manager and then selecting Add Roles and Features from the Manage menu (you will find the tools on the feature list). The DNS Server tools include the DNS PowerShell module.

MIke,

Comment: boom -- that's it.  For the anyone else, here's a good link: http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/q-im-missing-some-windows-server-2012-administration-tools-how-do-i-add-them

I'd upvote for the speed, but I don't have the rep to do so yet :)

Comment: Glad I could help, could you mark the question as answered please?

Comment: yep, I'm able to in about 30 seconds

Comment: How do you install this via PowerShell?

Comment: For more recent Windows versions (e.g. Windows 10 October 2018 Update or later) you can install via the command line: 

`Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name Rsat.Dns.Tools~~~~0.0.1.0`

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347338/1703887